# Product of the following reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Thia is the question and my approach.

[image]

I just want to confirm if it is the correct product. I have not gone for elimination as it will give anti-aromatic product.

Comment: I have a vague feeling that we're in for something more spectacular.

Comment: It's actually not anti-aromatic because the two double bonds aren't conjugated...

Comment: @Zhe It would obviously have been an anti-aromatic structure.

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan No, you're missing the point. Aromaticity and anti-aromaticity require that the $\pi$ system is conjugated. Cyclobutadiene can be formed, and it circumvents the problem of anti-aromaticity by not conjugating the two pairs of $\pi$ bonds. It's rectangular and not square as you might expect with resonance. So, it's neither aromatic or anti-aromatic because the system isn't conjugated.

Comment: @Zhe This is a new thing for me. In my school, it is taught for it to be plainly anti-aromatic, not going into further discussion. Anyways, do you think of any other product than cyclobutadiene?

Comment: Well, it turns out you don't isolate the cyclobutadiene because it immediately reacts with itself. Your job is to figure out what that reaction is.

Comment: @Zhe That’s wrong terminology. The double bonds *are* conjugated, there is no way around that. The distortion is there to remove the degeneracy since that would imply a diradical structure. Nonconjugated double bonds can be found in cyclooctatetra-1,3,5,7-ene.

Comment: @Jan Fair, but they're not fully conjugated. If you start increasing the separation, the orbital overlap decreases rapidly.

Comment: @Zhe What’s ‘fully conjugated’? They either form a pi system or they don’t. In cyclobutadiene, they do.

Comment: @Jan Let's just take this to chat.

Comment: Anyone got to a conclusion?

Comment: @ReeshabhRanjan the product you suggested is not aromatic since all atoms don't have the same hybridization .Moreover the molecule is non planar.one more thing,why did you go in for substitution .Alcoholic KOH is used only for elimination reaction and aqueous KOH for substitution.

Comment: @aniline Yes but according to me, it will give an anti-aromatic product. I don't know what Zhe and Jan are talking about, because I have not learnt of any such exceptions from anti-aromaticity.